# Java spring boot - retrieve dynamic inputs

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I'm trying to build a small QCM Application:

You have an quiz that have multiple questions and therefore multiple potential answer. The user can select only one answer between all (using radio buttons).

The user submit the form, but now i'm trying to retrieve the answers that the user selected on the server but I have not much clue on what to do because those fields are dynamic.

```
<form method="post" th:action="@{/score}" class="qcm-questions">

    <input type="hidden" name="id_quiz" th:value="${id_quiz}" />
    <input type="hidden" name="pseudo" th:value="${pseudo}" />

    <fieldset class="qcm-questions-item" th:each="question: ${questions}">
        
        <h2 th:text="${question.getLabel()}"></h2>
        <small th:text="'Question ' + ${questionStat.index}"></small>
        
        <div th:each="answer: ${question.getAnswers()}">
            <label th:text="${answer.getLabel()}" th:for="${answer.getId_answer()}"></label>
            <input type="radio" th:id="${answer.getId_answer()}" th:name="${question.getId_question()}" th:value="${answer.getId_answer()}" />
        </div>

    </fieldset>

    <button>Soumettre QCM</button>
</form>
```

**The only method I found is this :**

```
 @PostMapping
    public String registerScore(@RequestParam("id_quiz") final long id_quiz, @RequestParam("pseudo") final String pseudo, ServletRequest request) {

        Map<String, String[]> answers = request.getParameterMap();
        answers.remove("id_quiz");
        answers.remove("pseudo");

        return "page";
    }
```

Maybe you have a better idea than this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can retrieve inputs from a form through parameters or modelattributes.
I found personnally the model attribute solution easier and below is a code to do it like so.

I have created 2 modelattributes that I pass to the controller.
The first one will contain all the quiz details and the second one will be the answers collected in you form.
Modelattributes are objects and of course you can adapt the entities.

```
@Controller
public class FormQuizController {
@GetMapping ("/quiz")
  public String main(Model model) {
      Question quest1 = new Question();
      quest1.setId(1);
      quest1.setLabel("What is the answer?");
      Answer answer1 = new Answer (1, "answer 1");
      Answer answer2 = new Answer (2, "answer 2");
      Answer answer3 = new Answer (3, "answer 3");
      Answer[] answers = {answer1, answer2, answer3};
      quest1.setAnswers(answers);
      Question quest2 = new Question();
      quest2.setId(2);
      quest2.setLabel("What is the answer again?");
      quest2.setAnswers(answers);
      Question[] questions = {quest1, quest2};
      Quiz quiz = new Quiz();
      quiz.setId_quiz(1);
      quiz.setPseudo("Quiz 1");
      quiz.setQuestions(questions);
      ResultQuiz resultQuiz = new ResultQuiz(0,"init", new int[questions.length],new int[questions.length]);
      model.addAttribute("quiz", quiz);
      model.addAttribute("resultQuiz", resultQuiz);
      return "quiz";
  }
  @PostMapping ("/score")
  public String score(@ModelAttribute ResultQuiz resultQuiz) {
      System.out.println(resultQuiz);
      return "score";
  }
}
```

The method main is creating a quiz with 2 questions and 3 answers for each questions. It is also creating a resultQuiz initialized with fake data.
the method score is retrieving the result of the quiz through the object ResultQuiz.

Below the classes for domain (getters/setters/constructors omitted for brevity):

```
public class Quiz {
  private int id_quiz;
  private String pseudo;
  private Question[] questions;
}

public class Question {
  private int id;
  private String label;
  private Answer[] answers;
}

public class Answer {
  private int id;
  private String text;
}

public class ResultQuiz {
  private int id_quiz;
  private String pseudo;
  private int[] id_question = {0,0};
  private int[] id_answer = {0,0};
}
```

Then the code for the html pages using thymeleaf.
th:object indicates the object linked to the form. Then you can bind data directly.

To access values of an attribute with thymeleaf you just need to indicate the name of it.

iter variable gives you the index of each iteration.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>test form</title>
</head>
<body>

<form method="post" th:action="@{/score}" th:object="${resultQuiz}" class="qcm-questions">

<input type="hidden" th:name="'id_quiz'" th:value="${quiz.id_quiz}" >
<input type="hidden" th:name="'pseudo'" th:value="${quiz.pseudo}" >

<p th:text="'Valeur de resultQuiz:'+${resultQuiz}"></p>

<fieldset class="qcm-questions-item" th:each="question, iter: ${quiz.questions}">
    
    <h2 th:text="${question.label}"></h2>
    <small th:text="'Question ' + ${iter.index}"></small>
     <input type="hidden"  th:name="'id_question['+${iter.index}+']'" th:value="${question.id}" >
    <div th:each="answer: ${question.answers}">
        <label>
        <span th:text="${answer.text}" th:for="${answer.text}"></span>
        <input type="radio" th:name="'id_answer['+${iter.index}+']'" th:value="${answer.id}" />
        </label>
    </div>

</fieldset>

<button type="submit">Soumettre QCM</button>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

And finally the code for the score html page:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
    <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>test form</title>
    </head>
    <body>
      <span th:text="'For Quiz '+${resultQuiz.id_quiz}+' with name '+${resultQuiz.pseudo}"></span>
      <h2>Results are:</h2>
      <p th:each="question, iter: ${resultQuiz.id_question}">
      <span th:text="'For question '+${question} +' answer is '+${resultQuiz.id_answer[iter.index]}"></span>
      </p>
    </body>
    </html>
```